# How to add some custom behavior to Spring Data Jpa generated query?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data Jpa with a legacy Oracle database. Some of our tables used **char** instead of **varchar2** type. That causes some issue when I am using Spring Data Jpa generated query.

For example, I have an entity which named User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4054737587007197812L;

    @Id
    private Long userId;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "char", length = 12)
    private String username;
}
```

My UserRepository is like:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public User findByUsername(String name);
}
```

As usual, the Spring Data will generate a query like **select * from users where username = ?**. But since my Oracle database is using char type for column username, I will not get any result if I passed in the username parameter without padding enough space.

```
userRepository.findByUsername("Chris") -> not result
userRepository.findByUsername("Chris[with 7 spaces]") -> 1 result
```

Is there anyway to add some custom code to Spring Data Jpa and let Spring Data Jpa pads the spaces automatically? I don't want to write all query method again and pad the space manually since I have added the length in the Entity class ().

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this in JPA because you would probably have columns of different sizes.  If you are using Hibernate, this could be achieved using user types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate as the JPA provider, this can be achieved by creating a [Hibernate UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html).

1. Create a custom user type called `CharType`.  Perform the necessary padding and trimming within this class.
2. Annotate fields with `CHAR(n)` as the backing datatype to use `CharType`.

A complete solution, along with the `CharType` class is [available on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-oracle).  See the [Person](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-oracle/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/domain/Person.java) entity and test cases in [PersonRepositoryTest](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-oracle/blob/master/src/test/java/org/example/data/PersonRepositoryTest.java) for guidance on how to integrate something like this in your own code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But only for ojdbc7. ojdbc6 doesn't support ParameterMetaData.getPrecision(index) method.

Comment: Besides, I have another issue. If I update grade to ojdbc7. I have **ORA-00942: table or view does not exist** error.  I am using Spring Boot now and I have set the spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=my_oracle_username

Comment: For some reason OJDBC6 does not implement most of the `ParameterMetaData` methods.  This is not a deficiency in the Hibernate UserType solution but utter disregard for end-user requirements and JDBC spec on part of Oracle so there isn't much we can do.  My experience with the Oracle drivers has been to set the schema name in the JDBC URL as `jdbc:oracle:thin:<schema>@//<server:<port>/<tnslistener>` instead of setting the schema name for the JPA provider.  Make sure you are not setting the schema name in both places as the driver will then prefix table names with the schema name twice.